# How to write Regex In Spark SQL Spark 1.6 with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark 1.6 with scala

i am trying regex in spark sql.

In Spark Dataframe one of the columns contain value like

```
COLA

A0001

B5678

""

NULL

0012A6

B12345678
```

I am trying to filter all those records where colA values not start with a letter followed by 4 digit number.

Output will look like

```
""

NULL

0012A6

B12345678
```

As these are invalid number.

i tried this in mssql like

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{4}
```

How can we implemented in Spark sql. kindly share your suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A negation of a simple Regex condition using `rlike` should be all you need:

```
val df = Seq("A0001", "B5678", "", null, "0012A6", "B12345678").toDF("c1")

df.where($"c1".isNull || ! $"c1".rlike("^[A-Za-z]\\d{4}$")).show
// +---------+
// |       c1|
// +---------+
// |         |
// |     null|
// |   0012A6|
// |B12345678|
// +---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use rlike on your dataframe

```
df.filter($"COLA".rlike("[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{4}"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it is showing error near \d, do i need to import any library, i am using spark 1.6 with scala. kindly suggest.

Comment: GenericDisplayName: Error:(183, 54) invalid escape character
    df.filter($"COLA".rlike("[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{4}"))